# Differences between single and double backslashes

Tags: php, string, comparison, pcre, backslash

How can i check if there is odd or even backslashes before a character?
PHP sees single and double backslashes same!
Please look at codes below:

```
$str = "\a\\b\\\c";
echo preg_replace("/\\\/", "+", $str); // +a+b++c
echo preg_replace("/\x{005c}/u", "+", $str); // +a+b++c

echo strlen($str); // 7
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++)
    echo bin2hex($str{$i}).', ';
// Output: 5c, 61, 5c, 62, 5c, 5c, 63
```

I want to check that character has been escaped or not!

---

How to check differences between these two strings: "**\a**" , "**\\a**"?
like date() function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`\a` might be the same as `\\a`, but `\n` is definitely not the same as `\\n`. If the backslash with the next character resolves to a special sequence, the backslash acts as an escape character. Otherwise, the backslash is just a backslash.

Comment: How to parse it like date() function? It means odd-backslashes are not equal to even-backslashes?

Comment: You need to diferrentiate between string literal syntax, and the string contents. As @dgunchev says, your string is `\a\b\\c`, because \\ is an escape sequence for \, and `\a`, `\b` and `\c` are not valid escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is actually `\a\b\\c` - `\a` is invalid escape sequence hence it becomes `\a`, try however `\n`, which is valid, to see the difference.

Comment: Actually i want to simulate backslash escaping. Please consider rewriting date() function. So i need to parse a string and do something with odd and even backslashes differently.

Comment: Not sure I get you here, but to make things simpler try reading your input from a text file (say line by line), not embedding it in the code. When your are embedding it the PHP interpreter processes the backslashes first. Or try:

`$bsl = "\\";`
`$str = $bsl."a".$bsl.$bsl."b".$bsl.$bsl.$bsl."c";`
...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't with a regex. You can't do variable length look-behind assertions needed to guarantee that. I managed to write a regex that did a very good job of looking for such strings, even optimised with once-only subpatterns but it could occasionally cause a buffer overflow and crash the script when lots of matches occurred.

Have a look at at `strcspn()`. It's very good for writing custom parsing functions. You can use `\` as your stop character. Then with the next character, act on it if it's special, or jump ahead if it's not. It also runs faster than regexes.